# Using Demotic Alef unicode character with Noto font package and pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, unicode, greek, characters, noto

I'm editing some documents for my institution and need a few Demotic (ancient Egyptian script) characters:

- *Alef:* `ꜣ` and `Ꜣ`; Unicode: `U+A723` and `U+A722`.
- *Ayin:* `ꜥ` and `Ꜥ`; Unicode: `U+A725` and `U+A724`.[^1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration_of_Ancient_Egyptian#Unicode)

It **has to be compiled** with `pdfLaTeX` using the `noto` font from TL. The original Google Noto font, from which the `noto` package is a drawn, supports all of these characters.

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I tried the simple `\char"A723`. As it didn't work out, I tried some simpler characters. It is possible to produce an `ä` with `\char"00E4`, but even the try to produce a `λ` with `\char"03BB` throws an error. That the `noto` font package **can** produce Greek letters is obvious (like in math or with `\usepackage[greek]{babel}`).

This may be kind of a beginner's question, but I have no experience with those special characters, thus, any help is appreciated.

Here's a short MWE (with the different tests and a working lambda):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,english]{babel}
\usepackage[light]{noto}

\begin{document}

\char"00E4 % German ä

% \char"A723 % Demotic Alef

% \char"03BB % lambda

\foreignlanguage{greek}{l} % lambda

\end{document}
```

Comment: pdftex is 8 bit; fonts have at most 256 characters and `\char"FF` is the highest value so `\char"A723. ` can not work, why can you not use luatex which can use unicode?

Comment: if you need only a few: make small pictures with the standalone package + lualatex and include them with \includegraphics.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the fast explanation. I knew about the general restricition of pdftex, but not the concrete border. So far, I can't use luatex simply because the template I have to use is bound to pdflatex. I will try to change that, since not being able to use such charactes may be a strong argument for my supervisors...

Comment: For the specific problem, I'll get @UlrikeFischer hint a try. I'll provide an answer as soon as I realised it.

Comment: to be precise: you can use such characters with pdflatex, after all you also can use chinese or arabic with pdflatex. It is only much more work to set it up (and requires quite some knowledge).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sounds interesting. For the current case this seems too much effort. But in general I would like to get somewhat deeper into this stuff. My knowledge isn't that bad, but fonts are one of the topics I didn't had much to do with so far (except simply using them in documents, of course).

Comment: @lukeflo a Unicode font can have thousands of characters, so to make available from pdftex you have to choose multiple 256-character subsets in some custom encoding,

Comment: Thank you both. I now got it working with `lualatex`, even if not everybody here will be happy about the compiler change. But, unfortunately, now as compiling with `lualatex` the LGR encoding for Greek letters (outputting Greek letter with Latin input) doesn't work anymore. I'm currently checking on a solution for this... If I got both working, the topic should be solved.

Comment: @lukeflo LGR is as I describe above, a custom pdftex encoding mapping Greek to ascii slots below 256. for luatex you can use standard unicode Greek

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks. I know that I can directly input Greek letters using luatex or xetex. But most of our researchers (its ancient history, archaeology and classics; no computer scientist) are used to use [beta-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Code) for inputting Greek texts, LGR is only slightly different. So it would be great to use LGR input with `lualatex` just for their convinience. But that may be stand-alone question and, right now, I'm looking for a solution in the web, because nobody needs [duplicates] here ;)

Comment: you could use lgr or suppotr beta-code exactly with a bit of lua

Comment: @lukeflo oh it's done already babel has support for beta-code in luatex https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/106#issuecomment-743743030 (that was the feature request which is closed as it's now added)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, really nice. Just tested it and it works fine. Thank you! Would you like to provide a short answer, if you want also with the beta-code addition? Then I can accept it and mark the question as solved.

Comment: @lukeflo better if you post a tested self answer, it's all Greek to me... (I can survive without the +15 points:-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint by @UlrikeFischer and @DavidCarlisle I came up with the following solution (as someone can already guess from the comments):

For those few very special Demotic characters its of course the easiest way to use `lualatex` and the respective unicode values. A solution for `pdflatex` is possible but means too much effort for a few characters.

Since in my case we especially deal with ancient scripts it was important to keep the possibility of typing ancient Greek text using LGR or beta-code. Thus, the initial need for `pdflatex`.

But there are already two little bit hidden features of the `babel` package which offers the possibility to use beta-code.

1. The [`ibycus-babel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ibycus-babel) offers full beta-code support, but with a fixed font which is not changed by the set main font etc. Also compilable with `pdflatex`!
2. A not yet submitted and neither fully elaborated `babel` version [`betagreek`](https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/106#issuecomment-743743030) which, as of today, doesn't support all beta-code modificators, but is affected by the chosen font (as long as the font supports the Greek characters)

So here is the document which solves the unicode question and offers examples for both Greek typesetting possibilities (has to be compiled with `lualatex`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NotoSerifNerdFont-Light.ttf}
% \usepackage[light]{noto} % Can process ibycus-input with pdflatex, but no unicode
\usepackage[ibycus,english]{babel}

\babelprovide[import=el]{betagreek}

% In the following, more rules for transliteration have to be declared
\babelprehyphenation{betagreek}{ ([ahiuw]) = }{
  string = {1|ahiuw|ᾶῆῖῦῶ},
  remove
}
\babelprehyphenation{betagreek}{ ([aehiouw]) {)} / }{
  string = {1|aehiouw|ἄἔἤἴὄὔὤ},
  remove, remove
}
\babelprehyphenation{betagreek}{ ([aehiouw]) {(} }{
  string = {1|aehiouw|ἁἑἡἱὁὑὡ},
  remove
}
\babelprehyphenation{betagreek}{ ([aehiouw]) {)} }{
  string = {1|aehiouw|ἀἐἠἰὀὐὠ},
  remove
}
\babelprehyphenation{betagreek}{ ([aehiouw]) / }{
  string = {1|aehiouw|άέήίόύώ},
  remove
}
\babelprehyphenation{betagreek}{([abgdezhqiklmncoprstufxyw])}{
  string = {1|abgdezhqiklmncoprstufxyw%
             |αβγδεζηθικλµνξοπρστυφχψω}
}

\begin{document}

\char"00E4 % German ä

\char"A723 % Demotic Alef

\char"03BB % lambda

\begin{ibycus}
    ('Omhros
\end{ibycus}

\ibygr{a)rxai=a gra'mmata}

% Not all modificators are supported, e.g. majuskel:
\foreignlanguage{betagreek}{O('mhros. a)rxai=a gra/mmata}

\end{document}
```

(There seem to be more packages like [`teubner`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/teubner/) and [`betababel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/betababel) which I didn't test so far.)